# Python list of awaitable objects in de standard libraries

Tags: python, async-await, python-asyncio

I'm learning about Python async/await.

From [here](https://realpython.com/async-io-python/#libraries-that-work-with-asyncawait) I got a list of Python modules/libraries that work with async/await.
These are all libraries that give you "awaitable" objects.

But they all seem to be 3rd party libraries, i.e.: not part of the standard Python libraries.

The only awaitable example I know in the standard library is asyncio.sleep().

But there must be other calls that these 3rd party libraries make us of?
Or are they all directly implemented against some lower level C-library?

Does that mean that there is no standard library for async file IO? Or async networking?

This feels like something that should be in the standard libraries, doesn't it? (subjective question, I know)
Are there any plans to create/merge/include/... standard libraries for basic file IO and networking into the Python base distribution?

**EDIT**: I've answered my own question (1 minute after asking...). But I still dont know if this is what all these 3rd party libraries are using. Or if they are going directly to lower level C code?
OR: if [these](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-llapi-index.html) are the only async calls we can do (atm) in Python?

Answer (score 0):

Eh, just when you've given up, you see it's right under your nose:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-llapi-index.html

Lot's of stuff like:

- await loop.create_connection() Open a TCP connection.
- loop.add_writer() Start watching a file descriptor for write availability.

Comment: Don't use the low-level API such as `add_writer`. What you want is [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-stream.html#asyncio-streams) and [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-subprocess.html#asyncio-subprocess).

Comment: Thx! But do you know if this and this are indeed using these lower level API calls under the hood?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand what your asking. The linked classes and functions are part of asyncio, what classes they are internally implemented with is their implementation detail. As a user of asyncio, those are the abstractions for networking you refer to in the question, and that's what libraries like aiohttp use.